# Django custom user page

Tags: django, customization

I’d like to design a django page where a custom user, lets say a teacher class, can manage student users in a list with the ability to remove them from the site. This would be a sort of custom admin page, where the teacher would have the ability to manage students, but not have access to the actual django admin site. In the actual function of the site, students and teachers would see different pages based on their user type. What’s the best way to go about implementing this for someone not well versed in django?
edit: I should clarify this user manager page would not be the actual admin site, just a list box with users and the ability to manage them.

Comment: In case you missed that: when you define capabilities for roles, users logging into the admin will only see what they are allowed to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come in adminis , there is a tab , users , select the user ( teacher ) and gave him the 'User rights :' any you want.

or:

do it 'custom user model'

example:

```
 teacher = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='teacher', default=False)
```

and in admin for real teacher == BooleanField == True

```
@login_required
def deleted(request, id):
    context = {}
    complaint = Complaint.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.user.:
        complaint.is_deleted = True
        complaint.delete()
    context['deleted'] = complaint.is_deleted
    return redirect('complaints')
```